# Analytics shows less pageviews than adsense

Tags: google-analytics, google-adsense

I have been getting this for some time now

In my adsense performance reports i see that for a particular day in the past say 31 march 2016 i got about **1400+** page views.

The page views on the same date form Analytics is **500+** and this is not for a particular date. The difference is seen for each and every day.

I do not have any filters in my analytics that might filter the data.
I am using a self hosted wordpress site.

Why is there so much difference?
How can i solve this to reflect correct data?